# Is it faster to locating memory or doing calculation in register in mips?

Tags: mips, cpu-registers

In mips, there are too processes, like if I defined an array: space 10 in .data
There are two steps

1.

```
la $v0, array
```

2.

```
addi $v0, $v1
```

Which one is faster?

Comment: It may depend on the CPU the program is ran on.

Comment: `addi $v0, $v1` looks like a typo. `addi` takes three operands.